# Preserve order of rows when converting pandas Dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a pandas dataframe 'df' to dictionary using the command

```
df.to_dict( 'records')
```

Does this operation preserve the order of rows?

Comment: Answer aside, you could've easily confirmed this for yourself by writing a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Small example is a good start but it is not asserting the answer. The implementation is the only way to know for sure whether order is kept or not.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they do. Here are two dataframes:

DataFrame 1

```
    Cat Vec
0   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   a   [4, 5, 6]
2   b   [1, 2, 3]
```

Output:

```
[{'Cat': 'a', 'Vec': [1, 2, 3]},
 {'Cat': 'a', 'Vec': [4, 5, 6]},
 {'Cat': 'b', 'Vec': [1, 2, 3]}]
```

DataFrame 2

```
    Cat Vec
0   a   [1, 2, 3]
1   b   [4, 5, 6]
2   a   [1, 2, 3]
```

Output:

```
[{'Cat': 'a', 'Vec': [1, 2, 3]},
 {'Cat': 'b', 'Vec': [4, 5, 6]},
 {'Cat': 'a', 'Vec': [1, 2, 3]}]
```

Comment: I'll get on that train.  One of the biggest smiles I've had is when I saw @root use `np.random.seed([3,1415])` which is what I almost always use and no one else does because it's pi and well, you know...

Comment: I mean I can also see the output, but do you know for sure that it works for all dataframes?

Comment: Yes. I've used it to generate ordered reports. Lists are ordered so it follows that the output would be inn the same order.

Comment: Rows will be ordered but columns will not be (it will be sorted) when calling to_dict()